# render the simplest component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the simplest component ever in React, and after 
any closing HTML markup in return() everything is highlited in SublimeText3, 
and then it doesnt work at all

```js
var UserTable = React.createClass({
 render : function(){
  return(
   <h2> Random Content </h2>
  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(<UserTable />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

[image: Screenshot of Sublime]

Comment: You have to: import React from 'react';

Comment: save your file as .jsx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to import `react` and `react-dom` to your project. I managed to reproduce your code and it's up and running. However, if you mean simplest component as really *simplest*, I suggest using [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components):

```js
var UserTable = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <h2> Random Content </h2>
    )
   }
 })

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserTable />,
  document.getElementById('content')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I think its problem is that he is struggling to make react work on his website

Comment: Likely to to true as well. However by the way he asked his question I wrote the _simplest_ way as he requested.

Comment: of course. But a hint on why his code doesn't work would be nice too

Answer (score 0):

Welp, It was issue with http-server, it wasn't refresh at all ant thats why my content didn't upload. 
It wasnt synthax or sublime problem. Sorry 4 being sloppy